# Opencv Vs FFmpeg performance comparision for web cam feed recording

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ffmpeg, v4l2

I'm working on my academic project in which I've to record a video from the webcam.

In my google search, I've found that **FFmpeg** uses `pipelining` to record the video from the camera while **OpenCV**, **AVbin** use `ctypes`.

I don't know the pros and cons of either method, and wonder if you can help me decide which one to choose to write such kind of program in Linux.

I need to record 1024x768 30hz video and not experience latency/lag issues. Performance is the high priority.

Comment: Sometimes questions here are too broad, but this one ... is probably "too narrow" to receive much helpful answers. If you dont get good answers here: try looking out for user forums for those tools.

Comment: @GhostCat But StackOverflow has larger QA and can get quick responses. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I have asked more than one ffmpeg related question on the stackexchange network; and as you can conclude from my profile ... I do spent reasonable amounts of time here. And my intuition / gut feeling tells me "rather small chance for really helpful answers". Just encouraging expectations management here ;-)